# How to assign Files to Categories in DOCman?

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, extensions

I am new to Joomla and frankly feel like everything works the exact opposite of how I think it should... with that in mind:

I have been trying to assign Files to Categories in DOCman for longer than I want to admit. Is this a possibility? I have looked at some of DOCman's documentation and it has not clarified anything. I thought that a Document was basically a virtual version of a file, meaning I'd have a 1:1 ratio of Files to Documents, but I have zero Documents.

Is there a way to move or copy my Files into Categories? Or do I need to upload my Files/Documents directly into Categories?

ANY direction/help/criticism/personal-attacks would be appreciated. You are my only hope short of my intellect, and that seems to be at direct odds with DOCman...

Comment: https://support.joomlatools.com/tickets/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to Docman 3.1 you could select files and then click 'create documents' to make document records for all your files and categorise them at the same time.  This is now changed as documented here:
http://help.joomlatools.com/article/265-docman-3-0-to-docman-3-1#replacement-of-the-create-documents-flow

Currently it seems you have to make the documents at the same time as uploading the files. Furthermore the files interface will probably disappear entirely in an upcoming release.

Comment: Ah, this may be the issue. I am not seeing a "Create Documents" option, I have used my browser to search "Create" and still see nothing. Is this an option that has to be turned on somehow?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of what I'm seeing. Maybe I'm just missing where I should be looking or exposing that specific option. https://imgur.com/ylz4GyD

Comment: Apparently this is a new feature - I have updated my answer above.

Comment: Oh...I uploaded like 400 files to this site through FTP. I wonder if I can move them on FTP to a documents folder. Thanks for the help!

Comment: For anyone coming across this in the future, I never found a way to upload all of my Documents through FTP (the "Files" folder is easy enough to find, but no sign of "Documents" even after uploading some "Documents" through Joomla admin). There might be a Database approach, but that is outside my depth. Consequently, I uploaded all of the files directly through DOCman... it was a painful solution for me.